# Powershell moving files between folders

Tags: powershell, directory

I know there are lots of answers related to this problem, but they never totally do what I want.

I have a root folder, under that may be 1 or many subfolders. Initially files are created in the root folder `Rejected` and a program will try and process it and if unsuccessful move it too a particular sub-folder depending on the error. So in this case we have :

```
| - Rejected
    |
    | - duplicate_found
    |   | - Informed
    |
    | - no_name
        | - Informed
```

My program wants to loop through each of the subfolders (not the `Informed` folder), and keep a list of the files found in the subfolders and then send the list via email to a recipient who will then investigate.

After sending all files via email, I want to then move those files to the subfolder `Informed` related to its parent rejection reason subfolder.

So if file found in `duplicate_found` the file will be moved to `duplicate_found/Informed`. If file found in `no_name` then will be moved to `no_name/Informed` etc..

I can do the email part, it's the part of looping through each subfolder and then moving the file which I can't get a handle on.

I cannot do a complete folder move at the end of the process as new files may have come in that haven't been sent on the email. So whether I need to move the file while looping and also keep a list for the email at the same time. Not sure best approach.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example (PS 3.0 needed for the `-File` and `-Directory` parameters of `Get-ChildItem`):

```
#set root folder
$baseFolder = "C:\Rejected"

#get folders inside root
$folders = Get-ChildItem $baseFolder -Directory

#for each folder
foreach($folder in $folders) {

    #list the files
    $files = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -File

    #if there are files
    if($files.Count) {

        #build the move destination path
        $destination = Join-Path $folder.FullName "Informed"

        #move the files
        $files | % { Move-Item $_.FullName $destination }

        #build an email message with some information + the file listing
        $emailMessage = "$($files.Count) files reported and moved in folder $destination"

        #this could be formatted, i'm only pushing what you would see
        #in the console in the text message
        $emailMessage += $files | Out-String

        #i.e.: 5 files reported in folder duplicate_found and moved to
        #C:\Rejected\duplicate_found\Informed
        #
        # [file listing]

        #send email report for this folder

        $emailMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: That is excellent. Looks simple when you see the code, but finding what code to use always seems to be the hardest part. thanks

Comment: You are very welcome :-). If you like the answer, you can accept it by clicking the green check under its votes.